# Ignore accents in sqlite query appcelerator

Tags: sql, sqlite, appcelerator-titanium

does someone know what the equivalent to collate unicode on appcelerator using sqlite? In android studio it works but in titanium appcelerator it doesn't know what it is.

Android studio example:

```
"Select myData from myTable where myData == somthing order by myData COLLATE UNICODE"
```

I need the same query on appcelerator but the COLLATE UNICODE part doesn't work.

Iamguine the following:

Ao,
Ám,
Àn

I have words beginning with these letters.

If you order them:

Ám,
Àn,
Ao

but my query does not sort them how it should be.

is there any way to sort them without creating new columns in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNICODE` isn't a [built in](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collating_sequences) collation sequence. The [ICU](https://www3.sqlite.org/cgi/src/dir?ci=2e0357c2ed309279&name=ext/icu) extension lets you define locale-specific Unicode aware collators, but it isn't built by default in a lot of sqlite3 installs.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to do the same thing without using unicode?

Comment: @Manuel_Rodrigues what are you trying to do, exactly? What kind of sort ordering do you want?

Comment: @Manuel_Rodrigues Yeah, you're going to want to use the ICU collation definition functions. If you're using the amalgamation version of sqlite you can add `#define SQLITE_ENABLE_ICU 1` or the like to build it (And link with the appropriate libraries), or if it's a system library version, the extension can be built as a dll and loaded.